# Is this a right implementation of Layered Architectural Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I wanna implement The Layered Architectural Pattern to my solution. Can anyone give me the recommendation what should be modified in my structure template? Does it look good with the Layered Architectural Pattern implementation? Thanks

[Solution Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUaJM.png)

[Layered Architectural Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cg6Z.png)

## Update

Referred to [Peter Morlion post](https://blog.ndepend.com/software-architecture-5-patterns-you-need-know/#microservices), there is Presentation Layer on top of them, but in my project I am not gonna have presentation layer.

So the idea is:

- The Presentation Layer is where contains graphic design and handles user interaction.
- The Business Layer is where to handle business logic.
- The Application Layer is between Business Layer and Presentation Layer.
- The Data Access Layer contains code to access database.
- The Database Layer is used to define databases.

Comment: There is not enough info in that picture. The structure you have outlined is pretty generic and does not say enough about the linkages between elements. For example, I am not able to make out where the primary business logic resides in the business layer. Can you explain the various moving parts, how you intend to link them, and what their workflow is so that somebody can help?

Comment: Thanks @SubhashBhushan, I just added more details

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine from a typical MVC, n-tier architecture point of view, as used by standard frameworks like Ruby on Rails, Django, etc.

But you have tagged this question as "Domain-Driven Design," so I will answer from DDD principles. This code and dependency structure are not how you would design from a DDD perspective.

In DDD, your "Business layer", or the "Domain Model" as we usually call it, is at the center. It does not know or care about underlying infrastructure.

Concerns like Database, Cache, etc. are injected into the application layer dynamically through configuration, whenever necessary (even that can be avoided.) Outer layers including APIs, Controllers, Application Layer, Message brokers, etc. look inward into the Business Layer and use it to perform business

I suspect that all this might be difficult to understand outright from my simple statements. I would suggest you pick up a copy of [Domain-Driven Design Distilled](https://www.amazon.ca/Domain-Driven-Design-Distilled-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0134434420). It's a relatively small, concise book and gives a good intro into DDD.